# SQL Oracle multiply last digits of a string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a result of a query and need to get the last two numeric digits from a string column "contract"

[image]

The length of the string is not more than 3, and does not always have a digit

If the last two digits are numeric, then I want to multiply those numbers with 100. If the last 2 digits are not numeric, then I want to use a flat number of 20. How can I do this?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option: check whether the last character is a digit (that's what `regexp_like` does); if so, extract digits anchored to the end of the string (that's `regexp_substr`) and do the math. Otherwise, return 20.

```
SQL> with test (contract) as
  2    (select 'B01' from dual union all
  3     select 'M03' from dual union all
  4     select 'R22' from dual union all
  5     select 'NV'  from dual union all
  6     select 'BTB' from dual
  7    )
  8  select contract,
  9         case when regexp_like(contract, '\d$+') then regexp_substr(contract, '\d+$') * 100
 10              else 20
 11         end as result
 12  from test;

CONTRACT       RESULT
---------- ----------
B01               100
M03               300
R22              2200
NV                 20
BTB                20

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `... default ... on conversion error` feature of [`to_number`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html#GUID-D4807212-AFD7-48A7-9AED-BEC3E8809866) function to convert numbers to numbers and everything else to nulls. Then handle default value with `coalesce`.

> ```
> select
>   contract,
>   coalesce(
>     /*Try to convert last two digits to number and then multiply by 100*/
>     to_number(substr(contract, -2) default null on conversion error) * 100,
>     20
>   ) as num
> from input_tab
> ```
>
> | CONTRACT | NUM |
> | --- | --- |
> | B01 | 100 |
> | M03 | 300 |
> | R22 | 2200 |
> | NV | 20 |
> | BTB | 20 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=5b55447e0ac943cd158eddaa90c32c23)*